bidi document grouping, list environment and display math interaction
I'm trying to debug some of my code which works when everything is LTR and works when everything is RTL, but fails when main document direction is different to the direction inside one of my environments.
I've managed to reduce my code to something fairly simple, but I admit that it won't be clear from the question why on earth I'd want to do what I'm doing… Also, the behaviour is slightly different from my much more complicated real world code, so I may have missed something still.
The problem

In the code below, I use \predisplaysize to measure the length of the final line of a paragraph.
When you do this, you need to grab the \prevgraf from inside the display math in order to reset it afterwards to maintain spacing.
In the code below, the \prevgraf is reset 4 times at the end of each of my list environments. But it's value is different depending on whether I change the language before the first list environment or at the start of the list environment. In the MWE below each successive call of \measureline gives a \prevgraf of 1, 1, 1, then 0.

Why is this? And how can I get consistent behaviour?
I know the example is bizarre, but why should there be a difference depending on whether I call \setlanguage{ukenglish} before listenva as opposed to the first thing inside listenva???
(I want the behaviour of the second example in the MWE below. That is the pattern of \prevgraf for the four calls of \measureline should be: 1, 0, 1, 0. You can see this when you comment out \babelprovide[import, main]{persian}, ensuring that the language before the start of listenva is the same as what is set inside listenva)
Things I notice

Calling \@noparlistfalse before \endlist in the \listenvb environment is what is ensuring that \prevgraf is 0 at the second call. In other words if I comment this line out, \prevgraf is 1 for each of the four calls to \measureline.

The same problem occurs when main document language is LTR and my environment sets the language to be a RTL language.

Grouping is also affecting things:
This works:
\listenva
  \begin{listenvb}
    Test.
  \end{listenvb}
\endlistenva

But this fails:
\begingroup
\selectlanguage{ukenglish}
\begin{listenva}
  \begin{listenvb}
    Test.
  \end{listenvb}
\end{listenva}
\endgroup



MWE
%! TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{persian}
\babelprovide[import]{ukenglish}
\newdimen\linelen
\newcommand{\measureline}{%
  \abovedisplayshortskip -\baselineskip
  \abovedisplayskip\abovedisplayshortskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 0pt
  \belowdisplayskip\belowdisplayshortskip
  $$
    \ifdim\predisplaysize>0pt
      \global\linelen\dimexpr\predisplaysize-2em
    \fi
    \global\def\resetspacing{%
      \predisplaysize\the\predisplaysize
      \prevgraf\the\prevgraf
    }%
  $$
  \resetspacing
  \ifdim\linelen>0pt
    \vskip-\baselineskip
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\nolistspaces}{%
  \leftmargin 0pt
  \rightmargin 0pt
  \itemindent 0pt
  \partopsep 0pt
  \parsep 0pt
  \topsep 0pt
}
\newenvironment{listenva}{%
  \selectlanguage{ukenglish}%
  \list{}{\nolistspaces}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \measureline
  \strut\hskip\linelen+++%
  \csname @noparlistfalse\endcsname
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{listenvb}{%
  \list{}{\nolistspaces}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \measureline
  \csname @noparlistfalse\endcsname
  \endlist
}
\begin{document}
\begin{listenva}
  \begin{listenvb}
    Test.
  \end{listenvb}
\end{listenva}

\selectlanguage{ukenglish}

\begin{listenva}
  \begin{listenvb}
    Test.
  \end{listenvb}
\end{listenva}
\end{document}

Wrong output I'm getting

Desired output


I wonder if it’s related to \parshape, which is somewhat problematic in luatex. Lists are the only place where \parshape is used by LaTeX (iirc). It‘s just a hypothesis, I haven't investigated.

@JavierBezos looking at it more, the thing I really don't get is the grouping. Provided the language change is at the top level and not inside a group, things work like I expect. But as soon as \selectlanguage is inside a group the behaviour changes. I have quite complex \parshape in my actual code (in addition to the lists), and even that works if the language change happens at the top level.

Consider the following
\showboxdepth\maxdimen\showboxbreadth\maxdimen
\tracingonline1\tracingoutput1
\everypar{\setbox0=\lastbox}
{%\textdirection=0
$$
$$\par}
\bye

which gives the output
\vbox(667.20255+0.0)x469.75499, direction TLT
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 14.0fil, direction TLT
..\glue -22.5
..\hbox(8.5+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.755fil, direction TLT
...\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x234.8775, glue set 626.20251fill, direction TLT
..\glue(\topskip) 10.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted 234.8775, direction TLT
..\penalty 0
..\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 7.0 plus 3.0 minus 4.0
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\glue(\baselineskip) 17.55556
.\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 232.37749fil, direction TLT
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
..\tenrm 1
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil

while if I uncomment \textdirection=0 the output is
\vbox(667.20255+0.0)x469.75499, direction TLT
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 14.0fil, direction TLT
..\glue -22.5
..\hbox(8.5+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.755fil, direction TLT
...\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 614.20251fill, direction TLT
..\glue(\topskip) 10.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.755fil, direction TLT
...\localpar
....\localinterlinepenalty=0
....\localbrokenpenalty=0
....\localleftbox=null
....\localrightbox=null
...\begindir TLT
...\penalty 10000
...\enddir TLT
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
..\glue(\baselineskip) 12.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted 234.8775, direction TLT
..\penalty 0
..\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 7.0 plus 3.0 minus 4.0
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\glue(\baselineskip) 17.55556
.\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 232.37749fil, direction TLT
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
..\tenrm 1
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil

It looks like when you push explicitly a dir node (using \textdir) in a group, LuaTeX does not discard the empty line before the display (maybe it does not donsider it empty because of the dir nodes around the penalty). Not sure if that should be considered a bug or not.
I'm not proficient in babel's code, but my guess is that babel does not inserts dir nodes when it does not need to, and so when you put \selectlanguage{ukenglish} at the top grouping level, babel does not inject more dir nodes inside the group of your environment.
You can probably get by without using the display trick to get the last line length if you are willing to use some lua:
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{persian}
\babelprovide[import]{ukenglish}
\newdimen\linelen
\directlua{
 local disabled = true
 local function lastline_length(head,c)
    if disabled then 
        return head
    end
    local last_line = node.tail(head)
    local parfill_node
    for n in node.traverse_id(node.id('glue'),last_line.list) do
        if n.subtype == 15 then parfill_node = n end 
    end
    local length, _, _ = node.rangedimensions(last_line,last_line.head,parfill_node)
    tex.setdimen('global', 'linelen',length)
    return head
 end
 local getlastlinelength = luatexbase.new_luafunction"getlastlinelength"
 lua.get_functions_table()[getlastlinelength] = function() disabled = false end
 token.set_lua("getlastlinelength", getlastlinelength, "protected")
 local dontgetlastlinelength = luatexbase.new_luafunction"dontgetlastlinelength"
 lua.get_functions_table()[dontgetlastlinelength] = function() disabled = true end
 token.set_lua("dontgetlastlinelength", dontgetlastlinelength, "protected")
 luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter',lastline_length,'lastline')
}
\newcommand{\nolistspaces}{%
  \leftmargin 0pt
  \rightmargin 0pt
  \itemindent 0pt
  \partopsep 0pt
  \parsep 0pt
  \topsep 0pt
}
\newenvironment{listenva}{%
  \selectlanguage{ukenglish}%
  \list{}{\nolistspaces}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \ifdim\linelen>0pt
    \vskip-\baselineskip
  \fi
  \strut\hskip\linelen+++%
  \csname @noparlistfalse\endcsname
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{listenvb}{%
  \global\linelen=0pt
  \getlastlinelength
  \list{}{\nolistspaces}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \csname @noparlistfalse\endcsname
  \endlist
  \dontgetlastlinelength
}
\begin{document}
\begin{listenva}
  \begin{listenvb}
    Test.
  \end{listenvb}
\end{listenva}

\selectlanguage{ukenglish}

\begin{listenva}
  \begin{listenvb}
    Test.
  \end{listenvb}
\end{listenva}
\end{document}



Thank you. That is a much simpler example than mine. Is there any hope of a workaround? My actual environment takes a language=… key. And it's simply not always possible to make the language change at the top level (e.g., if my environment starts half way through a tcolorbox  or something like that). If it helps, I only plan to support RTL text with lualatex and babel.

@DavidPurton  babel does test in \bbl@setluadir if the requestion direction is already active and then doesn't issue a \textdir (but simply dropping the test would give wrong spacing in more cases so is not a simple way out). (BTW: the behaviour is more or less documented, the luatex manual says "paragraphs with only an indent and directions are handled as paragraphs with
content").

@DavidPurton I've edited the answer with a possible solution.

@UlrikeFischer Oh, so that is indeed not a bug, thank you for pointing that out! (although isn't the paragraph in my example does not contain an indent because of the \setbox0=\lastbox in the \everypar register?)

@UdiFogiel I only wrote "more or less documented" ;-). I'm not sure what is really going on here (and if there are options to avoid this side effect). It could make sense to ask on the luatex list.

@UdiFogiel, haha, there is always a lua solution. My code is a bit fragile and I'd love to try and avoid a radically different code pathway (already lots of test files trying to cover weird cases where my outer environment finishes with an inner environment). Also what is the function of the \setbox0=\lastbox? I notice that the spacing is the same for both cases without this. But as hinted at by Ulrike, putting \noindent before the display math $$ also exhibits the problem.

I also notice that both \pardirection and \textdirection need to be the same for the spacing to be different, otherwise both cases have a gap.

@UlrikeFischer, doesn't that indent line in the manual mean that there shouldn't be extra space added when I put \noindent in front of the display math? Without the \noindent, this code has a larger space: \pardirection=1\textdirection=1{\hrule\noindent$$$$\hrule}\bye. Still true that as soon as I put the direction changes inside the group, the output changes. IMHO, this is unfair :)

Can I tell some way if the \textdirection has been changed in a group above my environment (but not at the top level) and so then add a negative vertical skip if the direction inside my environment? (I would take Lua code for this.)

@DavidPurton The point in \setbox0=\lastbox is to remove the indent box so that the line will be empty, this is what lists do to remove the indent after them. This method will remove the indent box even if ther is an \indent after the list, I simply wanted to reproduce your problem with a more minimal example, and I kept this. I don't know what is you real use case, as you never really told us, but I don't think that the display trick is more robust from the lua solution I gave... I only removed the \measureline macro, pretty much else is the same.

@DavidPurton as for the last comment, maybe something like \newif\iffoo \let\origtextdirection\textdirection \def\textdirection{\ifnum\currentgrouplevel>0  \immediateassigned{\footrue}\fi\origtextdirection}

@UdiFogiel, that seems to work in my real code! It will solve my problem for this week, and I'll follow up with Ulrike as to whether this is something that should be fixed in luatex.
